# javascript pass element with set value onload

Tags: javascript, html, django

I have a small Django website, and I'm using a little Javascript on one of the pages to change a form for creating a new course. It lets the user choose the number of assessments students have to do with a select element:

```
<select id="number_of_coursework" onchange="put_assessment_forms(this)">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1" selected>1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    ...
</select>
```

The Javascript then generates the HTML according to `element.value` and puts it into the `innerHTML` in the website. That works fine.

My problem is that, in case the course already exists, I would like to have the page already set up to the right amount of assessments. How can I use `onload` in the body tag to call the function and to pass an element with a value of let's say 2? Or do I need to do this another way?

Comment: How are you checking the course already exists, just by a view? You should probably use [ajax](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/) to setup and process changes

Comment: That is passed on by the view to the template (basically the options are to either add a new module or to click edit on an old one, so it is either to see that before)

Comment: It seems your trying to implement logic that belongs in a view, not a template. You should check the status beforehand and display an EditView instead of CreateView if a condition is met.

Comment: The view determines that and then passes on a parameter called "add" (True or False) to the template. The template will only check `{% if add %}` to decide what the script should do onload.

Comment: The alternative will be to use two different templates, but I thought this would be a bit less hassle (and make it a bit easier to change later)

Comment: django implements very nice [generic views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/) for crud actions out of the box

Comment: I'm sure there are lots of other ways to do this, but my template works perfectly fine at the moment. I would just like to call the JS function with a set value to make it a bit easier to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say that your view checks the database and sees if the course exists. If the course exists, it sets `num_of_assessments = 2`, or whatever the actual number is. If the course does not exist, set `num_of_assessments = None`.

In your template, you could do this:

```
<select id="number_of_coursework" onchange="put_assessment_forms(this)">
    <option value="0" {% if num_of_assessments = 0 %}selected="selected"{% endif %}>0</option>
    <option value="1" {% if num_of_assessments = 1 %}selected="selected"{% endif %}>1</option>
    <option value="2" {% if num_of_assessments = 2 %}selected="selected"{% endif %}>2</option>
    ...
</select>
```

Comment: And I can call it when loading the page if I use `var element = getElementById(number_of_coursework);` instead of passing `this` on. Thanks!

Comment: If this post answered your question, please up-vote and accept the answer.